# Android JNI blocks on native to Java calls

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I have a pretty basic question regarding JNI calls to Java in Android NDK. I have no problems with making the actual calls, but I am not sure whether the Java call is blocked or not when it is called from C.
My question is specifically whether the c call blocks while the Java method is executed, or if it returns immediately. The reason I am asking is that I pass a byteArray to Java and I wonder if Java has access to it after the call is initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI calls are like nornal function call. Your native code continues running when JNI call (and Java function) returns.

Comment: Is there a way to make JNI Java methods block C++ execution? Is there an alternative workflow I am overlooking? Perhaps @dekz also has some input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about your selection of JNI calls, some can become blocking. For example getting a Critical pointer to a byte array and not releasing it can block the jvm from continuing to operate.